# Pass parameters to an event handler without creating a new reference of the handler everytime the stateless component re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

```
// @flow
import React from 'react';
import Input from 'components/Input';
import logo from 'assets/images/svg/logo.svg';
import styles from './style.module.css';

type TodoMethod = string => void;

type TodoProps = {
  todoList: TodoList,
  addTodo: TodoMethod,
  deleteTodo: TodoMethod,
};

// Return a function to delete a task
function getDeleteTodoMethod(taskName: string, callback: TodoMethod) {
  const deleteTodo = () => {
    callback(taskName);
  };

  return deleteTodo;
}

function Todo({ todoList, addTodo, deleteTodo }: TodoProps) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <header className={styles.appHeader}>
        <img src={logo} className={styles.appLogo} alt="logo" />

        <a
          className={styles.appLink}
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>

      <main>
        <Input onEnter={addTodo} />

        {todoList.map((item: TodoItem) => (
          <div key={item.index}>
            <span>{item.name}</span>

            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={getDeleteTodoMethod(item.name, deleteTodo)}
            >
              X
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Todo;
```

I have read in a post that functions should not be created inside a stateless component as re-rendering would cause a re-instantiation of the method. Hence, I created a function outside the component.

`deleteTodo` is an action that I want to call with a parameter whenever the button `DELETE TODO` is clicked. This could have been **easily accomplished** in **class-based components** via **composition**.

I could've simply created `() => deleteTodo(taskName)` and passed it as an event handler but with every re-render a new instance would have been created.

If I create a new stateless component called `Button`, it would lead me to the same problem of:

1. if I wanna access the prop `taskName`, I would have to create the function inside a stateless component
2. if I create a function outside the component, I have to somehow pass the parameter

Hence, I created a function which returns a named function.

```
// Return a function to delete a task
function getDeleteTodoMethod(taskName: string, callback: TodoMethod) {
  const deleteTodo = () => {
    callback(taskName);
  };

  return deleteTodo;
}
```

But, whenever the component re-renders, the named function would be assigned again as I feel there is no reference to the named function.

Is my interpretation correct? If yes, then how can I tackle this problem? How can pass a parameter to the handler without recreating the reference to avoid performance limitations?

Also, is there a way to test if a new reference of a function has been created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance impact of defining functions inside the render function is negligible, according to the official documentation:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#are-hooks-slow-because-of-creating-functions-in-render

If you want to prevent children from re-rendering when the callbacks change, use hooks to create a memoized callback:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Comment: Thank you. This helped. I upvoted but would wait for others to answer before accepting this as an answer :)

Comment: @rash.tay I edited my response to be more complete. With hooks you can create callbacks and it won't create a new instance no every render, so the children won't re-render

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot, Ricardo. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should first find out why the re-render happens. You have three property two of them are functions, those ones are not supposed to change ever.

So it probably happens because of the todolist, if the key (item.index) does not change for the existing items, react will know not to re-render them.

So you can do this:

```
<button
  type="button"
  onClick={() => deleteTodo(item.name)}
>
  X
</button>
```

There are other solutions like using React.memo, but you should use that only when you're sure it is necessary to prevent a re-render, since using React.memo also expensive, most of the time it is better if you let the re-render happen.

Comment: This is just an example. I am curious about knowing how can we tackle such situations when re-render occurs so that new references are not created. I do know that `todoList` makes the component re-render. Also, I am already aware of what you mentioned. I have asked this question to understand what React devs do in such a scenario. Thanks for helping though.

Comment: I see, well, first of all, you need to design your components carefully, have to know in which cases it will be re-rendered. 
You can use the reselect library, which will help you prevent unnecessary prop changes. as I mentioned you also can use React.memo and define your own logic for prop comparison, for function you can use the useCallback, but these ones should be used to avoid something that would take a lot of time to execute like a large component or a complex function.

Comment: True. But, think of a situation where the state changes from `loading: true` to `loading: false`. The component is going to re-render at any cost. 

`onClick={() => deleteTodo(item.name)}` would create a new reference of the function causing the child components to re-render.

Comment: Since react really fast, you should not worry too much about re-renders, most of the time prevent it cost more time to let it happen. (it doesn't mean you should not try to avoid them)

Comment: Your comment makes sense for small to medium scale application. But, for large scale/complex applications, performance would be vital. Unnecessary re-rendering would be a hindrance. But, I do agree with you to an extent.

Comment: here is an article about I wrote with further details:
https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback